# how to show additional links on your website in google search

Tags: html

I want to show additonal links like documentation, blogs associated to my website in google search result, like the image below

when we search for localytics, results also list links to documentation, blogs, etc.

please let me know how to do this.

[image: something like this]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Google:

> The links shown below some of Google's search results, called sitelinks, are meant to help users navigate your site. Our systems analyze the link structure of your site to find shortcuts that will save users time and allow them to quickly find the information they're looking for.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en